# combine lines of csv in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I want to create new csv file for each city combining several csv with rows and columns, one column has the name of cities, that repeat in all the csv files...

For example,

I have files with the name of the date,YYYYMMDD, 20140713.csv, 20140714.csv, 20140715.csv...

They have the same structure, same numbers of rows and columns, for example, 20140713.csv...

```
 1. City, Data, TMinreal, TMaxreal, TMinext, TMaxext, DiffTMin, DiffTMax
 2. Milano,20140714,19.0,28.8,18,27,1,1.8
 3. Rome,20140714,18.1,29.3,14,29,4.1,0.3
 4. Pisa,20140714,10.8,27.5,8,29,2.8,-1.5
 5. Venecia,20140714,21.1,29.1,16,27,5.1,2.1
```

I want to combine all these csv files...and get, csv files with the name of the city, as Milano.csv and inside with the information about this city stored in all the csv combined.

For example, if I combine 20140713.csv, 20140714.csv, 20140715.csv, for Milano.csv

```
 1. Milano,20140713,19.0,28.8,18,26,1,2.8

 2. Milano,20140714,19.0,28.8,20,27,-1,1.8

 3. Milano,20140715,21.0,26.8,19,27,2,-0.2
```

any idea? thank you

Answer (score 2):

untested, but this should work:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{next} {file = $1".csv"; print > file}' 20*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE; do
    {
        read  ## Skip header
        while IFS=, read -r A B; do
            echo "$A,$B" >> "$A".csv
        done
    } < "$FILE"
done
```

Then run as:

```
bash script.sh file1.csv file2.csv ...
```

Comment: Thank you Konsolebox, it runs also very well. One question, can you explain me the line,

Comment: A is the first column? a B the others columns? thank you

Comment: It splits the line into two by a comma. With `A,B,C`, A becomes `A` and B becomes `B,C`.